# solving for sequences convergent

Tags: sequences-and-series

is someone able to show me that the sequence is convergent or not.If the sequence is convergent,what would be the limit?

Maybe you could explain to me why:

$(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ with $a_n := \sqrt{2} \cdot (n-\sqrt{n})^{-2}$

thank you in andvance

Comment: You could treat it as a function... Easier to study ;-)

Comment: you heard of some test for convergence check?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compare $a_n$ with $C/n^2$ to apply comparison test. For $n\ge 2$,
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{(n-\sqrt{n})^2}&=\frac{1}{n(\sqrt{n}-1)^2}\\
&\le  \frac{1}{n(\sqrt{n}-\frac{\sqrt{n}}{2})^2}\\
&=\frac{4}{n^2}
\end{align}
and $a_n$ is always nonnegative. Thus $\displaystyle \sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{\sqrt{2}}{(n-\sqrt{n})^2}$ converges.

Answer (score 0):

HINT :

What's $\lim_{n\to \infty} n - \sqrt{n}$? You can rewrite it as $n - \sqrt{n} = \sqrt{n}(\sqrt{n} - 1)$ if it makes it simpler to see it's behaviour.

Having found the above, what's $\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{1}{(n - \sqrt{n})^2}$?

Comment: For the first hint $\lim_{n\to \infty} n - \sqrt{n}$ its $\infty$ right?

For the second hint $\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{1}{(n - \sqrt{n})^2}$ its 0 after puting $\infty$ into the fraction?

Comment: So the answer ist, yes it converges and the limit is Zero?  Right or Wrong :) ?

Comment: That's right. Don't forget to include $\sqrt{2}$ when you write it down. I omitted it because it doesn't do anything.

Comment: Thx a lot very clear presentation :)

Comment: Sorry I forgot to ask, does it have just one limit at $0$?

Comment: It does. The limit above is unique.